# php and sql 'INSERT INTO' not populating sql database

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

Thanks ahead of time.  I have checked the forum.
The php program allows a user to login and enter info into a mySQL database table `Names`.
It checks that all fields are filled in, 
that passwords match, 
that the user does not already exist.
This is one of several programs that work together

All of the code works except for one aspect.
It will not INSERT INTO the database table `Names`.

I ran into an analogous problem a couple of months ago.

QUESTION. Could the problem be that I have not set PERMISSIONS to allow a write to this table or database ?

QUESTION. Where are this files located to do this ?
Macbookpro.  OSX10.8.3.
PHP Version 5.3.15

Troubleshooting
1. I am connected to mysql database.
2. I am able to manually insert data into the fields.
3. All of the code below works; appropriate echoing dependent upon which fields are filled in or not.
4. The code does NOT give back any error messages.
5. Where in my code should I include    ??
die(mysql_error());
6. Why won't the data INSERT INTO ?

```
register.php
<?php
require 'core.include.php';  // it has the loggedin() function
require 'connect.include.php';
//require 'register.success.php';

if (!loggedin())  {
   // check if each form field is filled and correctly submitted

if(isset($_POST['username'])  &&
isset($_POST['password']) &&
isset($_POST['password_again'])  &&
isset($_POST['firstname']) &&    
isset($_POST['surname']))  {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_again = $_POST['password_again'];
    $password_hash = md5($password);
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];

// check if ALL fields are filled in
    if
        (!empty($username)&&
        !empty($password)&&
        !empty($password_again)&&
        !empty($firstname)&&
        !empty($surname))   {

        if(strlen($username)>30||strlen($firstname)>45||strlen($surname)>45) {
            echo 'please adhere to maxlengths of fields';
        }else{
            if($password!=$password_again) {
                echo 'Passwords do not match.';
                }else{

                    // start the registration process
                    // check if the user already exists in the database

                    $query = "SELECT `username` FROM `Names` WHERE `username` = '$username'";

                    //if the above $query returns a row than the user already exists

                    $query_run = mysql_query($query);

// I am unclear about what the above standard function actually accomplishes

                    if (mysql_num_rows($query_run)==1) {
                        echo "The username '.$username.' already exists";
                    }else{

                        //start the registration process
$query = "INSERT INTO `Names` VALUES 
        (' ',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($password_hash)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($firstname)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($surname)."')";  

        if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

    // if this query is successful:  mysql_query($query))  
    // we locate the user to a page so they do not keep over registering 
    // echo 'registered';

        header('Location:register_success.php');
        } else {
      echo 'Sorry, we could not register you at this time.';

// this is the problem.  
// this message always returns when I attempt to register a new user.
     }
   }
  }
 }
                   ////  echo 'Okay.';  // testing
                   ////  echo "The username '.$username.' already exists";  // testing
                  // note.  below inline php code will use the variables 
                  //so that if the user types in 4 of 5 fields they will 
                  //not have to retype in all of the fields again.

        } else{       
          echo 'All fields are required.';
     }
   }
?>

Register Form:
<br><br>
<form action = "registration.php"  method ="POST">
    Username:<br> <input type ="text" name ="username" maxlength="32" value = "<?php 
if (isset($username)) {echo $username;} ?>"><br><br>
    Password:<br> <input type ="password" name ="password" > <br><br>
    Password Again: <br> <input type ="password" name ="password_again" > <br><br>
    Firstname:<br> <input type ="text" name ="firstname" maxlength="45"value="<?php     
if (isset($firstname)) {echo $firstname;} ?>"><br><br>
    Surname:<br> <input type ="text" name ="surname" maxlength="45" value = "<?php 
if (isset($surname)) {echo $surname;} ?>"><br><br>
    <input type ="submit" value ="register"><br><br>
</form>

<?php  
    //echo 'register';
    }else if (loggedin ()) {
    echo 'you are already registered and logged in.';
    }    
?>
```

Comment: You don't check for errors.  Use `mysql_error()` to see what's wrong. Or run it from the command line.

Comment: off topic, but: If you are trying to learn using mysql in php (which it seems like), don't use the `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated and have some serious issues.

Comment: Refer to: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php Update your mysql to mysqli.. 5.5.0 deprecated mysql_ commands.

Comment: What is your Table 'Names' columns? do you have those lined up correctly? if it helps you could change it to say..  "INSERT INTO 'Names' (username, password, firstname, surname) VALUES ( ..... )";

Comment: Try specifying columns. You are indicating a space `' '` as your first column insert. Maybe you're attempting an insert on a field that doesn't take data or won't accept an empty field?

Comment: Wow. Thanks. What a receptive group.  I just jumped back on to add this specifically.  Return (coded) 'sorry, we could not register you at this time.'   I have been using tutorials and want to complete the series.  Thank you about the alert to deprecation.  I am not opposed to mysqli but cannot jump right now.

Comment: The first field ' ' is the id field which auto increments.  When I attempted to use the php code to Manually insert the data into mysql and  I was getting syntax errors.  By using a value (15) for that first value, it did insert values but actually inserted the entire code ".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."  I hope this does not cause a digression in the thread.  I am getting return text after I click submit.... 'Sorry, we can not register you at this time' which is in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging this issue, in your code, after the `mysql_query` call returns FALSE, use the `mysql_error()` function to retrieve the MySQL error message.

For example:

```
        } else {
      echo 'Sorry, we could not register you at this time.';

// this is the problem.  
// this message always returns when I attempt to register a new user.

      // for debugging: echo mysql_error(); or 
      die('error: '. mysql_error());
```

The error message should indicate whether it's a syntax problem, whether the number of values you are inserting match the number of columns in the (implicit) column list, whether the rows violates a constraint, whether the user has insufficient privileges issue, etc.

---

With an INSERT statement, it's best practice to explicitly list the columns that are receiving the values, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO foo (fee, fi, fo, fum) VALUES ('e','i','o','u');
```

Then your statement won't be later "broken" if a new column is added, or if the order of the columns is changed.

---

If it's a permissions/privileges problem, then you'd need to `GRANT` appropriate privileges to the mysql user you're connecting as. For example:

```
GRANT INSERT ON mydatabase.`Names` TO myser@myhost;
```

The privileges are stored in the mysql database, in the `user`, `db` and `tables_privs` tables. Privileges can be granted globally, on all databases (`... ON *.*`), at the database level (`... ON mydatabase.*`) or at the individual table level (`... ON mydatabase.mytable`)

Comment: thanks. progress. I inserted you suggested code.  Returns: 'sorry, we cannot register you at this time.'  Incorrect integer value: for column 'id' at row 1.  Sounds like the error.  My columns in the table:Names are id (auto increment), username, password,first name, surname.  I want the 'id' to auto increment to be the identifier field.  That is why I use '' to indicate empty value for this first value.

Comment: I understand you second suggestion: explicit code for columns and values.  It is a web based registration.  I am using php code (in my initial post on this topic).  Sorry about the bother but this is a tutorial series that is rather good and I just want to get through it (and onto more current coding strategies).  The code seems direct and logical and now that we see the error (which I do not know how to proceed with) can you please continue with this thread.

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion: you can either insert `NULL` or a zero to the AUTO_INCREMENT column, or can omit the AUTO_INCREMENT column from the INSERT statement. e.g. **`INSERT INTO foo (id, bar) VALUES (NULL, 'a')`**, or **`INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('a')`**.

Comment: :)  :)  thank You ! That did it ! You are very intuitive and this logical simple fix was just what I hoped for. My cont. troubleshooting for others. I inserted 'NULL' for the first value in the code and received this error: Sorry, we could not register you at this time.error: Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'id' at row 1; NULL not 'NULL' as You coded above-WORKED. $query = "INSERT INTO `Names` VALUES (NULL,'".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($password_hash)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($firstname)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($surname)."')";

Comment: How do I mark your response as the 'correct answer' ? and i am looking at your other responses to my more generic questions. again thanks.

Comment: Regarding GRANT and global privileges.... Last month, I totally mucked by setting a password within the database. I confused this with configuration settings for a password coming at it for terminal.  I took a look at what you explained about navigating and modifying things from within the database.  Not necessary now since all privileges are granted.  Generic question.  PhpMyAdmin is the title on the left frame of the window.  The URL says: localhost/phpMyAdmin/etc....  Cont.

Comment: Below the words phpMyAdmin (left frame) is the list of Databases. In the right frame server:localhost database:databaseName. Tabs: structure SQL search query etc...  Generic question.... PhpMyAdmin is the fronted application that allows manipulation of SQL databases ?  At one point, I recall using SQL but do not recall that I used other software to enter. I may be wrong. Can you explain this if you have a chance.  You are really good :)